# CString assignment is changing value of GetLastError()

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I am using MFC `CString` objects for strings. I am having an issue where setting a `CString` is causing `GetLastError()` to be set to something unexpectedly.

Below is a simplified version of the problem that shows the issue:

```
CString csTest;
DWORD dwLastError = 0;

SetLastError(0);
csTest = _T("test");
dwLastError = GetLastError();  // dwLastError is still 0, as expected
csTest = "another test";  // Not using TCHAR
dwLastError = GetLastError(); // dwLastError now set to 122, "The data area passed to a system call is too small."
```

I can reproduce this issue using Visual Studio 2015, creating a brand new MFC project (Dialog based), and adding this code in in the `OnInitDialog()` function of the dialog it made.

I am aware the first string is a `TCHAR`, which by default in this project will be a `WCHAR`. So it seems the `CString` assignment operator for a `char*` is causing the problem.

Is there a way to fix this? A way to get compiler warnings to inform me of a `char*` assignment instead of `WCHAR*`? I thought it used to give warnings/errors for this in some prior versions of Visual Studio, but does not seem to now, so maybe I am misremembering.

Comment: any api function call can change value of `GetLastError`. in what is problem ?

Comment: `GetLastError()`, unlike similar mechanisms in other languages, is not a catch-all function for every potential error within your code. @IInspectable goes into more detail in their answer below, but basically you should only be using `GetLastError()` as a validation mechanism both when the documentation says you should use it, and when you use it immediately after whatever it is you're checking. Anything else, and you're not using it correctly within C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable implicit narrow-wide conversions by defining the macro `_CSTRING_DISABLE_NARROW_WIDE_CONVERSION`, as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#remarks-8).

But that just helps you work around the *real* issue: You are simply calling `GetLastError` too late. Its return value will only be valid, until you invoke another call. Just don't do that.

Now even if you succeed in preventing any conversions, the `CString` implementation still has to allocate memory. When you run out of luck, `operator new` (which calls `malloc`) will have to reach out to the OS' memory management functions.

The solution is simple: Call `GetLastError` only, when the documentation tells you that it will return a valid value, and don't intersperse **any** calls to **any** functions.

Answer (score 1):

When assigning ANSI to `CStringW`, WinAPI `MultiByteToWideChar` is called. It's somewhat similar to the following:

```
csTest = "a"; // <- step in to this line with debugger
->
wchar_t *buf = new wchar_t[10];

MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, "a", -1, buf, 1); 
//Error 122, ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER
//MultiByteToWideChar is expecting 2, not 1, for len

DWORD err = GetLastError();
delete[]buf;
```

The problem occurs because `CString` uses the length of `"a"` and it doesn't account for the null character. `MultiByteToWideChar` sets the error.

`CString` later fixes the problem but the `GetLastError` is still set.

Just use `csTest = L"a";` to avoid the need for conversion. Or `csTest = CA2W("a");`

Otherwise `GetLastError` shouldn't be used in this way. Use `GetLastError` immediately after a WinAPI function fails.

Testing:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <AtlStr.h>

int main()
{
    DWORD err;
    CStringW str;

    wchar_t *buf = new wchar_t[10];
    int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, "a", 1, NULL, 0);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, "a", -1, buf, len);
    err = GetLastError();
    printf("MultiByteToWideChar error %d\n", err);
    delete[]buf;

    //Below is wrong usage of GetLastError(), it's only for this discussion...
    SetLastError(0);
    str = "a";
    err = GetLastError();
    printf("assignment operator error %d\n", err);

    SetLastError(0);
    str = CA2W("12345");
    err = GetLastError();
    printf("CA2W error %d\n", err); 

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
MultiByteToWideChar error 122
assignment operator error 122
CA2W error 0
```

Comment: `CA2W` will still perform a conversion. Nothing to be gained from that.

Comment: @IInspectable `csTest = CA2W("a")` will not affect `GetLastError`, it immediately adds room for null character. Unlike `csTest = "a"`.

Comment: Neither one is safe. It's not like `operator new` creates memory out of thin air. At one point it will hit the OS' memory management functions. There's simply no conceivable way to use `GetLastError` outside its documented specification.

Comment: @IInspectable This is basically an issue with `CStringW`'s copy constructor and assignment operator which don't account for the null character right away. It's not due to shortage of memory. `CStringW str = L"a"` and `CStringA = "a"` will also call `new`... `csTest = CA2W("a")` will not affect `GetLastError` the same way.

Comment: You are wrong. `operator new` **will** set the last error code, if heap has been depleted, and new memory needs to be acquired from the OS. You cannot safely call `GetLastError` outside its documented specification. It **is** that simple.

Comment: @IInspectable You are just guessing that the system ran out of memory and there isn't an extra few bytes available for `L"a"`. You can duplicate `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` with the code shown above. `csTest = CA2W("a")` will not set `GetLastError`

Comment: No, I'm saying, that it's not safe to invoke `operator new` and assume, that it will always persist the last error code. I'm also not saying, that the process ran out of memory, just that the heap manager isn't able to find memory with sufficient size and alignment requirements. It will then reach out to the OS, either allocating new memory, or committing previously reserved memory. I keep repeating myself here: You cannot call `GetLastError` outside its documented specification. You appear to insist, that this were possible. Please provide prove.

Comment: The result I showed can be duplicated consistently. As opposed to heap fragmentation in x64 or some other memory issue. I think we are talking about different things. It doesn't matter, the question is really not that interesting.

Comment: `int main() { SetLastError(ERROR_UNWIND); while(new wchar_t[2]) { if(GetLastError() != ERROR_UNWIND) cout << "Ooops!"; } }` - Compile for 64-bits, let it run (minutes). Observe. Nice aspect about absolute statements is, that all it needs is a *single* counter example to refute them.